# Optimize Select in Select

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT ID, title, image, FROM items WHERE  ID IN (
  SELECT tags_relationships.post_id
  FROM tags_relationships
    INNER JOIN tags
    ON tags.tag_id = tags_relationships.tag_id
  WHERE tags.name = 'white'
  ) 

AND
 ID IN (
  SELECT tags_relationships.post_id
  FROM tags_relationships
    INNER JOIN tags
    ON tags.tag_id = tags_relationships.tag_id
  WHERE tags.name = 'bike'
  ) 

 AND status = 'publish' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1860,20
```

Hi , again.
I have this query when someone searches for a "white bike", the result works just fine, dumping all the items heaving white and bike tags.
The problem with this query is that takes too much time >2 seconds because the items table has around 200k rows and tags_relationships around 1.5 mil rows.
I've tried to work on indexes but i know there should be an similar approach to my query resulting into a faster interrogation.

Comment: First you need to get your indices absolutely right, before you try to modify a query. I've got to note that MySQL is not as smart as you wish it to be with the execution plan, so it is not uncommon that you need to redesign your database and tables if performance is really slow.

Comment: Indexes are right, first time without indexes was taking 40 seconds to run a query

Comment: Just changing the subqueries to joins will increase a little bit the performance for this query. Would you able to do it?

Comment: Jorge , no . I've tried with joins but not good luck to translate this into a joining query.

Comment: Well a thing that I note on your query is the use of LIMIT clause. This is very painfull on mysql. Since it have to fetch the entire data then filter for the limit you impose. So try to take this clause off and put some more filters to the query to attend your requirements. And, post your attempt to use joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equivalent query 
* if tags_relationships have unique pairs of (post_id, tag_id)

```
SELECT items.* FROM items 
INNER JOIN tags_relationships r1 ON (r1.post_id = items.id)
INNER JOIN tags_relationships r2 ON (r2.post_id = items.id)
INNER JOIN tags t1 ON (t1.tag_id = r1.tag_id)
INNER JOIN tags t2 ON (t2.tag_id = r2.tag_id)
WHERE 
    t1.name = 'white'
AND t2.name = 'bike'
AND items.status = 'publish' 
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

But, it is fully equivalent, including execution plan because 'IN (subquery)' construction is inner join itself in case of unique join fields.
Primary key or unique index for tags_relationships should be complex (post_id, tag_id).

Comment: two unnecessary joins, since you can use `IN` for the tags names.

Comment: it returns zero results. If i remove the `AND t2.name = 'bike'`, then i get some results

Comment: Changed r1.tag_id to r2.tag_id (mistake);  Join are nessesary because you need AND condition for tags, not OR - so you are searching for such ITEM which coud be found in TWO tag sets (r1 and r2)

Answer (score 0):

How about this,

```
SELECT 
ID, 
title, 
image 
FROM items 
WHERE  
ID IN 
(
SELECT tags_relationships.post_id
FROM tags_relationships
INNER JOIN tags
ON tags.tag_id = tags_relationships.tag_id
WHERE tags.name IN ('white') AND tags.name IN ('bike')
) 
AND status = 'publish' 
ORDER BY ID DESC 
LIMIT 1860,20
```

Comment: There is a problem with `AND` clause. `MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)`. I am sure I have white & bike tags assigned to multiple items

Comment: try to execute queries with breaking down them, ex, execute only the subquery that I have specified, then check the result.

Comment: Yes, this is what had done, `SELECT tags_relationships.post_id
FROM tags_relationships
INNER JOIN tags
ON tags.tag_id = tags_relationships.tag_id
WHERE tags.name IN ('blue') AND tags.name IN ('bike')`

Comment: Now try something like,  [  SELECT 
ID, title,image 
FROM items 
WHERE  
ID IN ('the_prev_op_of_subquery')
AND status = 'publish' 
ORDER BY ID DESC 
LIMIT 1860,20   ]